# Best way to get string representation of object attribute

Tags: oop

This is a software design / best practices question.
What is the most elegant way to conveniently get a string value for an objects attribute?

Consider this example:

I have a model with numeric values saved as integers.

```
class Person {
   integer time_of_birth; // unix timestamp
   integer gender; // 1 - male, 2 - female
   integer height; // number of millimeters
   integer weight; // number of grams
   string name;
}
```

To create meaningful views (HTML page for example), I need to output numeric information in human-readable form - string. So far I am doing it by adding methods "attributename_str()" that return string representation of a non-string attribute.

```
method time_of_birth_str() {
   return format_date_in_a_sensible_manner(this.time_of_birth);
}

method gender_str() {
   if this.gender == 1 return 'male';
   if this.gender == 2 return 'female';
}

method height_str(unit, precision) {
   if unit == meter u = this.height/some_ratio;
   if unit == foot u = this.heigh/different_ratio;
   return do_some_rounding_based_on(precision,u);
}
```

Question is - is there a better way to do this, without creating numerous formating methods? Perhaps a single static formating method? How do you do this numeric value formating?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a person object here and they are responsible for quite a few things:
1) Formatting dates
2) Converting gender between a flag and a string
3) Converting measurements

It's a best practice to limit your object to a single set of related responsibilities.  I would try to create a new object for each one of these.

In fact, if I was being strict about the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), I would even recommend a Measurement class for converting between various values (store your conversion constants here), and another MeasurementPrinter class that would be in charge of formatting it in pretty ways (e.g. 6 feet, 2 in or 6' 2", etc).

Just to give you a concrete example of what I mean

```
 public class Person {
   private Height height;
 }

 public class Height {
   private static final double FT_TO_METERS = // just some example conversion constants

   private int inches;

   public double toFeet() {
     return inches / IN_PER_FEET;
   }

   public double toMeters() {
     return toFeet() * FT_TO_METERS;
   }
```

So now person knows nothing about converting measurements.

Now like I said, I might even make a printer object like:

```
   public class HeightPrinter {

     public void printLongFormat(Height height) 
     {
       print(height.getFeet() + " feet, " + height.getInches() + " inches");
     }

     public void printShortFormat(Height height) 
     {
       print(height.getFeet() + "', " + height.getInches() + "\"");
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get away with a single formatting method since different attributes have different requirements. But a couple of guidelines can make your life much easier:

**Separate the view code from the model code:** Have a separate `PersonView` class that returns information suitable for your HTML output:

```
public class PersonView {
  private Person person;

  public String getTimeOfBirth() {
    return formatDate(person.getTimeOfBirth());
  }

  ...
}
```

**Use strongly typed properties instead of primitives:**

- Use a date object instead of an integer timestamp.
- Create an enum for gender instead of an integer.
- Create a height and weight class with units instead of integers that assume units.